# Finding Ranges Inside NSString Separated by a String

Tags: iphone, ios, string, substring

Although iOS provides a lot of useful string methods, I can't find a good solution for getting ranges of strings that are separated by a given character.

**original string:**

> |You| will |achieve| everything you |want| if you |work| hard

separateness character is `|`.

separate string1: You     (range: 3, 3)

separate string2: achieve (range: 12, 7)

separate string3: want    (range: 37, 4)

separate string4: work    (range: 51, 4)

NSString method's `substringFromIndex:` makes it possible to find these ranges using NSString, but this seems inefficient.

Please, let me know the better ways to solve this.

Comment: NSString's methods are there for exactly this purpose. You don't have to worry about the performance: they are optimized well enough. Consider using `rangeOfString:`, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [NSRegularExpression](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [matchesInString:options:range:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009708-CH1-SW6) method.

> **Return Value**
>
> An array of [NSTextCheckingResult](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppKit/Reference/NSTextCheckingResult_Class/Reference/Reference.html) objects. Each result
>   **gives the overall matched range** via its range property, and the range
>   of each individual capture group via its rangeAtIndex: method. The
>   range {NSNotFound, 0} is returned if one of the capture groups did not
>   participate in this particular match.

You might have code like:

```
NSString *str = @"|You| will |achieve| everything you |want| if you |work| hard";
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:
    @"[^|]*" options: 0 error:nil];
NSArray *results = [regex matchesInString:str 
                                  options:0 
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [str length])];
// ... do interesting code on results...
// Note that you should iterate through the array and use the 'range' property
// to get the range.

for (NSTextCheckingResult *textResult in results)
{
   if (textResult.range.length > 0)
   {
      NSString *substring = [myStr substringWithRange:textResult.range];
      NSLog(@"string at range %@ :: \"%@\"", 
            NSStringFromRange(textResult.range), 
            substring);
   }
}
```

Logs:

> string at range {1, 3} :: "You"
>
> string at range {5, 6} :: " will "
>
> string at range {12, 7} :: "achieve"
>
> string at range {20, 16} :: " everything you "
>
> string at range {37, 4} :: "want"
>
> string at range {42, 8} :: " if you "
>
> string at range {51, 4} :: "work"
>
> string at range {56, 5} :: " hard"

Comment: Wow, this method is the one that I want. Thank you very very much.

Comment: Shouldn't the regex be `@"\|([^|]*)\|"`? That should return only the 4 substrings being asked for. You would need to use `-[NSTextCheckingResult rangeAtIndex:1];` to get the range of the capture group, since `-[NSTextCheckingResult range];` would include the pipes.

Comment: @JustinAnderson You could do it that way, but you'd have to make sure every result begins and ends with a pipe (not sure that's necessarily the case).  You'd also then have to modify the ranges as you pointed out, but it would eliminate empty range matches that my answer falls prey to.  When I tried your expression I got "you" "achieve" "want" "work".  I modified your expression to not include the pipe at the end :: `@"\\|([^|]*)"` which now returns everything and without the empty entries that my results include.  I think your expression (modified) is better if the input is in that format.